# Information ID from Opencart twig

Tags: opencart

trying to get the full URL of a page including the page ID, in this instance, for an information page.

In my header.php controller file i have :

```
$data['currentURL'] = $this->url->link($this->request->get['route'], '', 'SSL');
```

But when i call that into my twig file using :

```
{{ currentURL }}
```

I only get 1/2 the URL :

```
index.php?route=information/information
```

Rather than :

```
index.php?route=information/information&information_id=10
```

Where have i gone wrong? And how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, where would i stick this?:-?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, this done the trick :

`$data['newURL'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

popped that into my header.php controller and it worked out! Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction!